# Formatting output into an html file for filtering [PYTHON]

Tags: python, html, xml, formatting, output

I've just written my first script for my first proper job (rather proud).

Basically I parse a large xml file that contains 3 types of data: estates, symbols and types.

It then creates 3 .txt files listing all items of the 3 types, one file for estates, one for symbols and one for types.

What I need to do now is format the output for use in our internal wiki.

I want to be able to filter it with a drop down menu, so that I can select an "Estate" and see what "Symbols" are in the "Estate" and then see what "Type" these symbols are.

For scope there are ~50 estates, ~26 types, and about 93000 Symbols (They all vary from day to day).

A symbol belongs to an estate and each symbol has a type.

If you want any code snippets from either the xml doc or my current script, feel free to ask, I didn't want to dump a load of code in here.

EDIT:

Here is an example of how the XML is formatted, showing the symbol name, its estate and then its type

```
<Symbol SymbolName="<SYMNAME>" Estate="<ESTATENAME>" TickType="<TYPE>" />
```

Names have been omitted for confidentiality.

EDIT2:

Had the idea of using dictionaries to better sort the parsed data.

Eg.

```
dictionary1 = {symbol1[estate], symbol2[estate]}
dictionary2 = {symbol1[type], symbol2[type]}
```

TO CLARFIY: I have a bunch of data from an xml that needs to be written to an output file in such a way that it can be filtered on a web page (drop down menus preferable)

Comment: Don't put that many questions in one. To help you with formatting the data, we probably need to know what Wiki you're using. If you want to know what UI to use, we need to know which options you have. If you need help filtering the data, then ask for that. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @AaronDigulla the wiki part is fine, there's a batch to upload stuff to the wiki (it's confluence). I don't understand what you mean by UI, I don't think I ever mentioned a UI. I have edited my question to clarify

Comment: You said "filter it with a drop down". Drop down == UI.

Comment: @AaronDigulla Understood, I understand why my question could seem complicated now.

Comment: The clarification doesn't help. Does your wiki support drop downs menus? If not, how do you plan to add one?

Comment: @AaronDigulla by having an html file embedded into the wiki page

Comment: Closing as "too broad". This site can't answer "write my code for me" questions. Cut the question down to something more simple (like "How do I embed arbitrary HTML into Confluence"). Then start working on the task and ask simple, concise questions when you hit a road block.